# Есть ли способ удалить/переопределить функцию?

Tags: php

Стандарт не позволяет. Но костыль может фанатики уже создали? Никто ничего подобного не слышал/видел?
Единственное, что удалось нарыть http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-function-redefine.php

Comment: Расскажите плиз подробнее зачем вам это нужно. Просто интересно.

Comment: На будущее!

Comment: да-да ООП.

Comment: namespace ?

Comment: отличный вариант  eicto .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ООП все уже реализовано. Создается абстрактный класс, в котором есть определенный набор методов с определенной функциональностью. Любой класс, который имеет расширение данного абстрактного класса сможет переписать любую функцию этого абстрактного класса.

Comment: zhenyab за наводку спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, это не совсем то, что вы ищете, но похоже:

```
function f1() {
    echo "1\n";
}
function f2() {
    echo "2\n";
}
$f = 'f1';
$f();          // вызовется f1
$f = 'f2';
$f();          // вызовется f2
```

Comment: Это не совсем то,но данный прием тоже полезен .